# Drawing a circle segment

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I wrote code to draw a circle segment, such that the segment angle will be facing the mouse.

My code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <math.h>

const float PI{ 3.14159265359f };

//convert degress to radians
float degToRad(float deg)
{
    return
        deg * PI / 180;
}


void drawCircleSegment(sf::RenderWindow & gameWindow)
{
    gameWindow.clear();
    sf::VertexArray arr(sf::LinesStrip);

    float segmentAngle{degToRad(45)};
    float radius{100};
    sf::Vector2f radiusPos{ gameWindow.getView().getCenter() };

    unsigned circlePoints{20};
    float angle{ 0 };

    arr.append(radiusPos);

    do
    {   
        sf::Vector2f mRelP //get relative mouse position
        {
            sf::Mouse::getPosition(gameWindow).x - radiusPos.x,
            sf::Mouse::getPosition(gameWindow).y - radiusPos.y
        };

        float mouseAngle{ atan2(mRelP.y, mRelP.x) }; //get angle between relative mouse position and circle center

        sf::Vector2f p
        {           
            cos(angle + (mouseAngle - segmentAngle / 2)) * radius, //position = cos(angle + lookAngle) * rad
            sin(angle + (mouseAngle - segmentAngle / 2)) * radius  //position = sin(angle + lookAngle) * rad        
        };

        p += radiusPos;
        arr.append(p);

        angle += segmentAngle / circlePoints;

    } while (angle < segmentAngle);

    arr.append(radiusPos);

    gameWindow.draw(arr);
    gameWindow.display();
}

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow gameWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "circle");
    gameWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);

    while (gameWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (gameWindow.pollEvent(event))
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                gameWindow.close();

        drawCircleSegment(gameWindow);
    }
}
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, this is pretty good. It's straightforward and to the point. Here are some other thoughts.

## Don't Declare `PI`

You don't need to declare π. It's already declared in `math.h` as `M_PI`. Though in C++, it's preferred to `#include <cmath>` instead, which will put the standard math functions into the `std` namespace. In C++11 and later, it's suggested to use a calculation to define it such as:

```
const auto kPi = std::acos(-1.0);
```

## Declare Functions `constexpr` When Appropriate

You don't say whether you're using C++11 or higher, or not. If you are, I would recommend declaring your `degToRad()` function `constexpr` so that it can be used in the definition of constants.

## Don't Repeat Yourself

You have some code inside your loop that always calculates the same thing each iteration. The definition of `mRelP`, and `mouseAngle` should be moved outside the loop so you do less work in the loop.

## Naming

`mRelP` is a confusing name. In many codebases it's a convention to prepend "m" to member variables. I'd just call it something more readable like `mouseRelPos`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @user1118321's answer:

### Less curly brackets in variable definitions

Things like `unsigned circlePoints{20};` and `float angle{ 0 };` aren't needed. Use `unsigned circlePoints = 20;` and `float angle = 0;`

> *Why?*
>   Because the kind of variable  definitions you use are less commonplace and don't make the code any better.

### Don't put code in the wrong places.

Avoid using once per frame functions *(such as `gameWindow.clear();` and `gameWindow.display();`)* in functions other than the main loop. They should go in `main` instead of `drawCircleSegments`.

> *Why?*
>   If you needed to call `drawCircleSegments` multiple times, the window would `clear` and `display` multiple times, which would not work well.